# Как работает этот скрипт получения дробной части числа?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которою я не понимаю

```
function getDecimal(num) {
  var str = "" + num;
  var zeroPos = str.indexOf(".");
  if (zeroPos == -1) return 0;
  str = str.slice(zeroPos);
  return +str;
}

alert( getDecimal(12.5) ); // 0.5
alert( getDecimal(1.2) ); // 0.2
```

Зачем для `var str нужные запятые и + num ??` И еще не понимаю что происходит в части `return +str` (я знаю что оно добавляет ноль перед запятой но не понимаю как.На сколько я понимаю здесь унарный плюс который указывает на что что число положительное)

Comment: `num` - это число, `str` - это его строковое представление. Число к строке в данном случае приводится с помощью конкатенации с пустой строкой (`"" + num`), Унарный плюс (`+str`) приводит строку к числу. В частности, строка ".5" превращается в число 0.5

Comment: @Regent Благодарю

Comment: "Зачем для var str нужные запятые" - а о каких запятых речь?

Comment: Капец как сложно... А `num % 1` религия написать кому-то не позволила? :-)

Comment: @Regent indexOf  не работает на числах?Только на строках?

Comment: @ZELIBOBA да, это метод, который есть [в String](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) и в [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну если таким способом то будет показывать неточно.Тогда приходится писать `Math.round(num % 1 *10)/10`; Уж легче написать `return +str`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function getDecimal(num) {
 var str = "" + num; // 1
 var zeroPos = str.indexOf("."); // 2

 if (zeroPos == -1) return 0; // 3
 str = str.slice(zeroPos); // 4

 return +str; // 5
}
```

Разберем по частям:
**1 строка**: приводим число к строке. Например: было `.5` стало `"0.5"`, ноль добавляется, так как `.5` расценивается как число и к строке приводится в таком виде.

**2 строка**: ищем в строке точку, которая отделяет дробную часть. `indexOf` возвращает индекс, где встретился символ или `-1` если символа нет.

**3 строка**: проверяем, если ли вообще точка в строке. Если нет, то число скорее всего целое ( скорее всего, потому что вообще может быть не число, проверок на `NaN` нет )

**4 строка**: разбиваем строку начиная с символа точки. Например: было `"0.5" => ".5"`

**5 строчка**: превращаем строку в число `".5" => 0.5`